# HTML(5) layout/structure help - beginner

Tags: css, html

I am wondering specifically about the wrapper and how to structure the site. I have all content contained within 960 pixels, except for the header image (which is below the navigation). I've attached an image below.

If I'm understanding correctly, I've read in some places to place the header image outside the wrapper, others say within.

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated, I know there are so many ways to do this, but I'd like it to be really clean and adhere to recent standards. I'm using HTML5, not that it matters much.

[image: layout]

Comment: Why 1600px may I ask?

Comment: @LiamSorsby probably to support bigger monitors. although I'd go upwards to 2000

Comment: You all are forgetting about my 4k TV -_-

Comment: @Cole"Cole9"Johnson too bad most of us don't have those laying around :P

Comment: @kennypu I actually wish I had one. Would it be possible to rig a couple of monitors together to make one?

Comment: @Cole"Cole9"Johnson if it's for PC, you probably can connect multiple monitors and just extend them. assuming you have input for all those monitors

Comment: @kennypu I don't think going up too much is necessarily a good idea; you're serving increasingly large images to the user, which increases loading time and makes the experience worse for the user. Also, OP may not have a larger-sized image.

Comment: This is a question I have had in the past as well. Would it be bad practice to create smaller unused DIVs around the corners to fill the space? Basically turning this into a grid-like layout.

Comment: I'm actually using 1920x1080 on my screen, but I chose 1600 due to the height of the header image; if I made it any wider, it would clip too much of the person's face out.

Comment: @kennypu That can make a line of monitors, but what I'm looking for would be a grid of monitors. Like I could connect 4 of the same size in a grid to turn a 1280x1024 into a 2560x2048...

Comment: I did design this in photoshop using a 12 column 960 grid.

Comment: @Cole"Cole9"Johnson yeah, you can do that. eg in windows, in the monitor/resolution settings, just stack the monitor on top, or to the side of your center monitor :). This means you'll need at least 4, or 9 monitors though obviously.

Comment: @kennypu Interesting, I'll have to look into that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a wrapper class, and but use it only where you need it. So, in your case it would go like this...

- Logo/Nav (wrapper class)
- Header
- Content (wrapper class)
- Footer (wide one)
- Footer (wrapper class)

That way, although it might seem chopped out, you'll get the desired behaviour, those elements in wrapper having the 'normal' width, while the other go the full width, by default.

See how that works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/shomz/acKvm/1/).

This is essential (and also obligatory by SO):

```
div {background: #eee; height: 50px;}
div.wrapper {background: #ccc; width: 200px; margin: auto;}
```

EDIT

And since you want to keep your footer together, not in two separate parts (which makes perfect sense), you can do this, it works too:

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class="wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

And if you don't want your wide elements to scale, you can define their width, too... Like having a bigger wrapper for those. You can also center the background and never worry about it (thanks @kennypu). Plenty of options once you tame your wrappers.

Note: I might've not used the proper terminology, as wrapper is wrapping only parts of the site and not the whole thing (maybe you can think of it as a limiter), but you get the point.

Comment: Ok, thanks so much, but I don't want the header image to scale, if that changes the code I'm not sure. I want it positioned in the middle of the screen and for the sides to disappear when you resize the browser.

Comment: @Stano Thank you very much, fixed it... No idea how I lost it.

Comment: @user2238812 just set the background image to position top center (assuming that's where you want it)

Comment: @user2238812 It doesn't have to scale, you can do whatever you want with it - define a bigger width, put margins, center the background (like kennypu said)... My code shows you how to 'lock' just certain part of your site, as opposed to having the whole site locked in a certain width.

Answer (score 3):

You can do your code like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="header wrapper">
        <div class="inner-content">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="main wrapper">
        <div class="inner-content">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer wrapper">
        <div class="inner-content">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper { width: 100%; }
.wrapper.header { background-color: #00f; }
.wrapper.footer { background-color: #f00; }

.inner-content { width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

Your wrapper class will contain your inner content and allow you to apply a color to each wrapper. The inner content will act as a container for the text and images.

Comment: Right, that's a good point, I never thought to use multiple wrappers. I wonder if there are any "best practices" when it comes to this. Which is why I guess I posted in the first place :)